# How to use rewrite in location block with condition properly?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to handle requests in nginx in such a way, so when the crawler comes to get a requested page I need to send a static version of single page application by requested URL, otherwise dynamically generated `index.html`.
Static and dynamic pages are located in different folders (required), so I use `$src` variable for this case.

My config:

```
server {
 listen       443 ssl http2;
 server_name  www.example.com;
 
 set $src "/www";
 set $crawler 0;

 if ($http_user_agent ~* "examplebot|anotherbot|crawlerbot") {
  set $crawler 1;
  set $src "/www-static";
 }

 root "/var${src}";

 location ~* ^/(en|us|uk)/products/ {
      if ($crawler = 1) {
          rewrite ^/(\w\w)/products/(\w+)/(\w+) /pages/$1/$2/$3.html break;
      }
  }
  
 location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
 }
}
```

With the config above, when I go to my website I get `404` error, even if through a normal user-agent (not crawler's).

Crawler request url: `https://www.example.com/en/products/dairy/cheese`

Static page location: `/var/www-static/pages/en/dairy/cheese.html`

---

My expectation is, when the crawler requests e.g. `https://www.example.com/en/products/dairy/cheese`, it should get the static page and when the normal user requests any page, he should get *index.html* located in root folder.

I know `if` statement in nginx is not the best thing in the world, but is there any solution to achieve what I want to, no matter with or without `if` or `rewrite` statements, thanks?

I'd like to note that the "redirecting" to the desired folder with `$src` variable without first `location` block works without issue. So, I think the problem is not linked to `$src` variable and its logic.

Comment: Your `location ~* ^/(en|us|uk)/products/` block is missing a `try_files $uri /index.html;` statement, which is the mechanism by which normal requests are sent to `index.html`.

Comment: @RichardSmith, thanks! It worked! And I understood why it helped.
By the way, you can answer my question instead of leaving your helpful answer as a comment! Then I will mark your answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic that sends requests to your `index.html` is the `try_files` statement. To replicate that behaviour for URLs handled by the `location ~* ^/(en|us|uk)/products/` block, you will need to add a `try_files` statement to that block too.

For example:

```
location ~* ^/(en|us|uk)/products/ {
    if ($crawler = 1) { ... }
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
  
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```